# Python, how to check if value changed in mqtt

Tags: python, infinite-loop, mqtt

I'm getting data from a machine sensor what gets kw. As a script I only need different KW numbers so that I can send it to database. I want to print "Same number" if the new number value equals to the last one(same number), else print variable number value if it has changed. How can I do that if its forever_loop? I already asked about this question, but that was when I'm using while loop without mqtt forever_loop, but I cant use while in this script.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
import pymysql.cursors

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe("QQ/QQ/QQQ/QQQ") #Just some random characters, I changed it


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    arv=int(float(msg.payload.split('   ')[0]))
    print(msg.payload.split('   ')[0])      

    if (arv>arv+1 or arv>arv-1):
        print("Same number {0}".format(arv))
    else:
        print(" Number is {0} ".format(arv))


client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.username_pw_set("blank", password="blank")
client.connect("local", 0, 0)
client.loop_forever()



Output:

6.12
Same number 6
6.91
Same number 6
6.38
Same number 6
5.44
Same number 5
6.75
Same number 6
6.50
Same number 6
6.15
Same number 6
5.67
Same number 5
5.80
Same number 5
6.21
Same number 6
5.21
Same number 5
6.25
Same number 6
6.66
Same number 6
5.14
Same number 5
```

Comment: The code you have posted is missing the `on_message` function definition

Comment: Typo, fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the last value in a global variable so you can test it on each new message:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
import pymysql.cursors

lastValue = 0

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe("QQ/QQ/QQQ/QQQ") #Just some random characters, I changed it


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    global lastValue
    arv=int(float(msg.payload.split('   ')[0]))
    print(msg.payload.split('   ')[0])      

    if arv == lastValue:
        print("Same number {0}".format(arv))
    else:
        print(" Number is {0} ".format(arv))

    lastValue = arv

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.username_pw_set("blank", password="blank")
client.connect("local", 0, 0)
client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: I'm getting an error " NameError: global name 'lastValue' is not defined "

Comment: Did you forget to add the `lastValue = 0` line at the top?

Comment: Yes I did, I'm sometimes soo blind and stupid. But thank you for your anwser, you helped me alot :)